# SymPy hangs up when trying to solve system of equations

Tags: python, sympy, jupyter-lab

I am trying to solve a system of two equations for two unknowns. Jupyter ran indefinitely in the attempt to solve these equations.
My code:

```
import numpy as np
import sympy as smp
#Enable LaTex display
smp.init_printing()

L1,L2,L3,L4,L5,theta1,theta2,theta3,theta4,theta5=smp.symbols('L1,L2,L3,L4,L5,theta1,theta2,theta3,theta4,theta5')
def position_vectors():
    R1=np.array([L1*smp.cos(theta1),L1*smp.sin(theta1)])
    R2=np.array([L2*smp.cos(theta2),L2*smp.sin(theta2)])
    R3=np.array([L3*smp.cos(theta3),L3*smp.sin(theta3)])
    R4=np.array([L4*smp.cos(theta4),L4*smp.sin(theta4)])
    R5=np.array([L5*smp.cos(theta5),L5*smp.sin(theta5)])
    return smp.Matrix([R1,R2,R3,R4,R5])
R=position_vectors()
print('Vector Matrix:')
display(R)

i_comps=smp.Eq(R[1,0]+R[2,0]+R[3,0]-R[0,0]-R[4,0],0)
j_comps=smp.Eq(R[1,1]+R[2,1]+R[3,1]-R[0,1]-R[4,1],0)
print('Vector Loop Equations:')
display(i_comps)
display(j_comps)

theta_solutions=smp.solve([i_comps,j_comps],[theta2,theta5],dict=True)
print(theta_solutions)
```

I am writing a report on this, so I need to have an analytical solution.

Comment: It looks to me like you have 10 unknowns 5 L's, and 5 thetas.

Comment: @Tim Roberts I am trying to solve symbolically.

Comment: What makes you think there is any kind of "solution"?  I think your expectations are unreasonable.

Comment: A solution is being sought for, essentially, `(L2*cos(x) - L5*cos(y) + i, L2*sin(x) - L5*sin(y) + j)`.

Comment: The equations can be solved but the solutions can be expected to be quite complicated so exactly what form you want them in depends on what the next steps in your calculation are. Most likely computing an explicit symbolic solution is not the best way to reach the end result of your calculation.

Answer (score 0):

Relieve SymPy of having to deal with terms that don't contain the symbols of interest:

```py
from sympy import *
# your code in SymPy flavor
L1,L2,L3,L4,L5,theta1,theta2,theta3,theta4,theta5=symbols('L1,L2,L3,L4,L5,theta1,theta2,theta3,theta4,theta5')

R1=[L1*cos(theta1),L1*sin(theta1)]
R2=[L2*cos(theta2),L2*sin(theta2)]
R3=[L3*cos(theta3),L3*sin(theta3)]
R4=[L4*cos(theta4),L4*sin(theta4)]
R5=[L5*cos(theta5),L5*sin(theta5)]
R = Matrix([R1,R2,R3,R4,R5])
i_comps=Eq(R[1,0]+R[2,0]+R[3,0]-R[0,0]-R[4,0],0)
j_comps=Eq(R[1,1]+R[2,1]+R[3,1]-R[0,1]-R[4,1],0)

# my suggestions
i,j,k=symbols('i j k')
ii, di = i_comps.lhs.as_independent(theta2, theta5)
ij, dj = j_comps.lhs.as_independent(theta2, theta5)
sol = Tuple(*solve((di + i, dj + j), theta2, theta5))
```

You will notice the appearance of `i**2 + j**2` and `(i**2 + j**2)**2` so you might want to replace those with a separate symbol `k = i**2 + j**2` by doing

```py
sol = sol.subs(i**2, k-j**2).replace(lambda x: x.is_Add, lambda x: expand(x))
```

Then collect the `k` terms:

```py
sol = sol.replace(lambda x: x.is_Add, lambda x: collect(x,k))
```

You now have a fairly compact Tuple of expressions which can be reported along with the definitions of `i` and `j` (though you might want to do so after running `cse` on the solution):

```
r, e = cse(sol)
r.insert(0, (i, ii))
r.insert(1, (j, ij))
r.insert(2, (k, i**2 + j**2))
for _ in r: print(str(_))

Eq(i, -L1*cos(theta1) + L3*cos(theta3) + L4*cos(theta4))
Eq(j, -L1*sin(theta1) + L3*sin(theta3) + L4*sin(theta4))
Eq(k, i**2 + j**2)
Eq(x0, -pi)
Eq(x1, 1/L2)
Eq(x2, -j*x1)
Eq(x3, L5**2)
Eq(x4, 2*L5)
Eq(x5, L2**2)
Eq(x6, 1/(i*x4 + k + x3 - x5))
Eq(x7, j*x4)
Eq(x8, x6*x7)
Eq(x9, sqrt(-L2**4 - L5**4 - k**2 + k*(2*x3 + 2*x5) + 2*x3*x5))
Eq(x10, x6*x9)
Eq(x11, -L5*sin(2*atan(x10 - x8)))
Eq(x12, 2*atan(x6*(x7 - x9)))
Eq(x13, L5*sin(2*atan(x10 + x8)))
Eq(x14, 2*atan(x6*(x7 + x9)))
Eq(x15, -j)

for _ in e[0]:print(str(_))  # solutions for (theta2, theta5)

(-x0 - asin(x1*x11 + x2), x12)
(-x0 - asin(x1*x13 + x2), x14)
(asin(x1*(x11 + x15)), x12)
(asin(x1*(x13 + x15)), x14)
```

Comment: IF you want to solve for specific values, I would recommend evaluating the equations before tyring to solve them, e.g. `reps = dict([(theta1, pi/6),(theta3,pi/4),(theta4,pi/7)]); solve((i_comps.subs(reps).n(),j_comps.subs(reps).n()))`.